# Sub works differently through button on the worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, module

So I've spent the evening trying to design snake in VBA. Great stuff. It seemed to be working fine whenever I ran the Main Sub from the VBA window (by clicking the play button in the top ribbon), however when I added a button on the worksheet for the same sub, it runs with no errors but the controls don't behave in the same way. Originally each time you press an arrow you just change direction, however when running the macro through a button you can keep holding the arrow in the direction you're going and it speeds up the snake, so the cell select behaves as it normally would in Excel, rather than as required in snake. This defeats the purpose of the game as the rest of the snake can't catch up with the head and creates gaps within allowing the user to just jump through it.

I'm using GetAsyncKeyState to read key presses:

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" _
            (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer
#Else
    Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" _
            (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer
#End If
Private Const VK_LEFT = &H25 'LEFT ARROW key
Private Const VK_UP = &H26 'UP ARROW key
Private Const VK_RIGHT = &H27 'RIGHT ARROW key
Private Const VK_DOWN = &H28 'DOWN ARROW key
```

And then calling this with If Statements:

```
' Key press handling
WasteTime (speed)
If GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN) Then
    PressDown
ElseIf GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) Then
    PressUp
ElseIf GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT) Then
    PressLeft
ElseIf GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT) Then
    PressRight
End If
' Offset by key direction or default
ActiveCell.Offset(cellrow, cellcol).Select
```

For reference, this is all that each key function does:

```
Function PressUp()

        cellrow = -1
        cellcol = 0

End Function
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I suspect this has something to do with me declaring the GetAsyncKeyState function in the General Declarations section, but as I've never done this before, can't quite work out what I'm doing wrong. Thanks :)

Comment: Try saving the value of the key press and do nothing if the next one is the same?

Comment: @TimWilliams I finally realised what the issue was, the difference between running the code from the developer window and from the worksheet was that in developer mode the cursor was staying within the code so the selection of cells didn't change. When I ran it through a button on the worksheet pressing an arrow key meant also selecting a new cell which then moved the snake a further cell. Pretty silly error, managed to fix this by protecting the sheet and disabling cell selection.